# Page flip transition into a custom url in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, transition

Okay, so my problem is that I want to make a page flip transition into this custom url that I am creating through javascript.

```
$("#btnSave").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = "mypage_with_params.html?" + selectedParams; //selectedParams is a list
    return false;
    });
```

What function can I call to make the window fire into this url with a page flip animation?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a pretty hard thing to do. Transitions between pages don't really work, though it's OK to transition to things on the same page, perhaps using AJAX.

I wrote a little bit up on how to do a basic flip here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/, though browser support isn't that great.

In order to simulate a page transition, you'd need to load the new page via AJAX into a div behind the current one, then flip from one to the other, then likely reset everything using JS.

Comment: I've given you an upvote but I cannot accept it as an answer in case there's actually some solution. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: There isn't a way to do a transition between real pages, only in the way I've said - sorry :(